# Least squares solution

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

It is known that the least squares solution of the equation

$A(t)x=b(t), x\in\Re^n, b\in\Re^k$

is given by the left pseudoinverse

$x^{LS}=(O^*O)^{-1}O^*b$

where $O:\Re^n\rightarrow L^2\left(\left[a,b\right];\Re^k\right)$, with $Ox=Ax$

and its adjoint $O^*$ is given by

$O^*b=\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt$ and $O^*O=\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt$,

if $O^*O$ is invertible.

Thus, the least squares solution is given by

$x^{LS}=\left(\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt\right)^{-1}\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt$

Conversely, if we are given the solution $x^{LS}=\left(\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt\right)^{-1}\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt$, how can we prove that this solution satisfies $A(t)x^{LS}=b(t)$, since there are integrals that cannot be eliminated?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The least-squares solution is given by
$$
x = (O^*O)^{-1}O^*b,
$$
which implies
$$
O^*Ox = O^*b,
$$ which does not imply
$$
Ox=b
$$
as $O^*$ is not necessarily invertible.

Comment: But shouldn't it be trivial that since least squares solution is a solution, it satisfies the equation? How can't this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think that we only take the left pseudoinverse in case $O^*$ is injective. By this, we have:

$w(t):=A(t)x^{LS}-b(t) \Rightarrow $

$A^*(t)w(t)=A^*(t)A(t)(\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt)^{-1}\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt-A^*(t)b(t)$ By integratingboth sides from $a$ to $b$, we take:

$\int_a^b A^*(t)w(t)dt=\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt(\int_a^bA^*(t)A(t)dt)^{-1}\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt-\int_a^bA^*(t)b(t)dt\Rightarrow$

$\int_a^b A^*(t)w(t)dt=0$

This means that $O^*w=0$ and since we have supposed that $O^*$ is injective, we must have

$w(t)=0$ and this proves that

$A(t)x^{LS}=b$